# Is there any free software for use with printed documents (for accurate CMYK)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, inkscape

I need to send redesigned business cards to a print shop.

I've tried GIMP and Inkscape (cards presently designed with GIMP with an embedded CMYK profile; I didn't have the computer knowledge to make use of the the work-arounds for Inkscape's CMYK issue), and both have lots me gobs of time (months) and thus money by going back and forth with the printer which apparently has been tweaking the colors at their end and usually not so successfully.

I never had such problems with Photoshop files, but my super old version (7 or 8?) stopped working and I couldn't reinstall because Adobe's server stopped supporting something to do with that process. Having moved to another state recently (with all of my old longstanding, reliable customers in another state), I am broke as can be and need free if at all possible.

Comment: Related answer: [How to embed a color profile into a PDF with Inkscape?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73082/68027).

Comment: Both GIMP and Inkscape have poor (or no) CMYK support. Inkscape in particular wasn't really designed for that. The questioned referenced by @Juancho is the appropriate solution with those tools.

Answer (score 3):

Try Scribus. https://www.scribus.net/

But I really feel the need to write something extra.

This is not meant as an insult in any way. On the contrary, **it is to encourage you**: Stop having a poor man's (woman) mentality.

> gobs of time (months) and thus money by going back and forth with the printer which apparently has been tweaking the colors at their end and usually not so successfully.

Doing things wrong costs money.

It is a big mistake on making a business card on Gimp, (inclusive on Photoshop).

If you are a designer it would be easier if you go and rent half an hour on a computer that has the proper tool to send the colors right. Make the shapes in Inkscape previously in your home and export that to Ilustrator or Corel, and reasign the colors there. But **only in the case you really need a cmyk output**, which I really doubt. That would be the case if you need like 10,000 business cards.

More likely you need 100 business cards. That is digital, and can be sent in RGB. Take a look at this: [How configure color in InDesign for a specific printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74365/how-configure-color-in-indesign-for-a-specific-printer/74367#74367)

Just tweek the colors yourself. **Make some swatches and choose the best RGB combination for your color.**

But if you are not a designer, the least problem you have is "not the perfect color" Your client will not care about that. Do you have a professionally designed logo and business card?

You could have a text only business card, but if the service you provide (flowers, food, a heavy manufacturing process) is good, the client won't care.

So stop waiting months for a "perfect" business card and go out and sell!

Comment: Just to clarify, the solution here is to do the design in Inkscape and then convert to CYMK using Scribus. You don't need to re-create the design in Scribus. Full details for the work flow are found in this question: [How to embed a color profile into a PDF with Inkscape](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55262/how-to-embed-a-color-profile-into-a-pdf-with-inkscape/73082#73082)